# Apply Power Series Solution Method on Solving ODE with non-integer x order term $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x^{1/2}y=0 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

**Problem:**
Use series solution expansion to solve ODE in region x>0

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+x^{1/2}y=0 $$

**Attempts:**

Assume $y=\sum^\infty_{n=0} a_nx^n$, then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=2} n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$.

The ODE can then be expressed in series expansion, followed by:

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}a_nx^{n+1/2} =0$

by switching indic, we get

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}+a_nx^{n+1/2}=0$

Here is where I get confused: for the equation to hold, every n substitution in the expression will result in 0 and the recurrence relationship can be obtained.

But here, say if I let $n=0$, the recurrence relationship will become involved with x, as shown,

$2\cdot 1\cdot a_2=a_n\cdot x^{1/2}$

But I doubt it is correct because then the constants $a_n$ will become x-dependent.

I also attempted to solve it on Mathematica, it seemed like somehow the solution can be found to be Bessel functions,

$y(x)=C_1\sqrt{x}\;\Gamma (\frac{3}{5}) J_{-\frac{2}{5}}(\frac{4x^{5/4}}{5})+C_2\sqrt{x}\;\Gamma (\frac{7}{5}) J_{\frac{2}{5}}(\frac{4x^{5/4}}{5})$

but I really am not sure whether that is correct or how to get there

Comment: In the same spirit as Frobenius method, you may allow non-integer powers from the very beginning, such as $y(x) = \sum_k a_k x^{kq}$ or $y(x) = \sum_k a_k x^{k+q}$, with $k \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: You may also consider the change of variable $t := \sqrt{x}$.